# Removing root xml tag from json result in asp.net web api 2 c#

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I would like to remove the root xml tag from json result retured from web API 2 method.
here is the code

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    var data = context.Languages
        .Select
        (lang => new
        {
            id = lang.Language_ID,
            title = lang.Name
        });
    //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
}
```

here is the result string

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    [{"id":1,"title":"Arabic"},{"id":2,"title":"English"},{"id":3,"title":"French"}]
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

your method returns a string thats why you get the string xml tag, try this instead

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var data = context.Languages
        .Select
        (lang => new
        {
            id = lang.Language_ID,
            title = lang.Name
        });
    //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
    return Json(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating new class and change the method as the following code

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<BasicItem> Get()
    {
        var data = context.Languages
            .Select
            (lang => new BasicItem
            {
                id = lang.Language_ID,
                title = lang.Name
            });
        //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        return data;
    }
```

the asp.net will automatically serialize it
to ensure that the returning result is json I added the following code to WebApiConfig

```
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new   MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```